# Workarounds to avoid Error: "Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Tags: soql, governorlimits, limits

I am hitting  salesforce limits in 3 cases:

1. When user is adding a document from a large list of docs which is
   greater than 100? (Eg error when they are trying to pull a document
   from their library that has 196 documents)
2. When processing a list
   of ATTACHMENTS greater than 100.
3. When an Opportunity has 100 contacts, the controller throws error.

There are two Opportunities that will show the error above:

1. Opportunity "Opp with 100 Contacts 1 Document", if we click on
   custom button on action.
2. Opportunity "Opp with 1 Contact 102
   Documents", if we click on custom button on action.

Any help with architecture redesign/ Work around/ better handling of such errors appreciated

Comment: Outside of the generic advice to "bulkify your Apex", we'll need to see code to help pinpoint trouble errors. Have you read any posts on bulkifying Apex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Exception: Too many SOQL queries: 101](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/system-exception-too-many-soql-queries-101)

Answer (score 7):

**I always like to think about future when I write code. I had a similar issue when I started writing Apex a few years ago, so not to worry you are not the only one.**

***Please look at my advices below:***

**1.** Read this article carefully: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code 
 **2.** Make sure you don't have a recursive loop calling a SOQL.
 **3.** Do not do any DML/CRUD inside a for loop. 
 **4.** Use System.Debug() to ensure what you are fetching is what you should be getting.
 **5.** Make use of the Debug logs/Developer console. Debug it, and you will figure it out.

**I am also happy to help with code if you can post it up.**

Answer (score 2):

In addition with above given points (consolidated):

- Avoid SOQL queries that are inside FOR loops.
- Make sure you don't  have a recursive loop calling a SOQL.
- Do not do any DML/CRUD inside a   for loop.
- Avoid more than one DML on single object in single
  transaction -  because each DML invokes trigger of related object can
  cause addition of SOQL count.
- Avoid  too many field updates in
  process builders in different conditional branches. Each branch runs
  a DML and initiate trigger execution.
- If there are lot of business processes and logic in your trigger then design and isolate processes with help of future and batch if needed.
- **Recursion Handling** - To ensure a trigger is not running recursively.
- **Minimize the No.of SOQLs by merging the queries** - we will merge the SQL query of single object in a single query if possible.
  For Example:

  Opportunity op = [select StageName, Account.OwnerId From Opportunity where id: opId];
  List olis =  [select id, productId from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId =: op.Id];

Change it to:

```
Opportunity op = [select StageName, Account.OwnerId, (select id, productId from OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity where id: opId];
```