# I am getting System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 error

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, errormessages, governorlimits

> for(Project_Milestone__c b: [Select
>   id,name,Project_Milestone_Percent__c,Payment_Schedule_Template__c,phase__c
>   From Project_Milestone__c WHERE Payment_Schedule_Template__c =:
>   PS_nomal ORDER BY Project_Milestone_Percent__c DESC ])

Comment: apt = new List<Apartment__c>();
    apt = [SELECT id,name,Phase__c,Total_Cost__c FROM Apartment__c WHERE id =: a];
    PhaseId = apt[0].Phase__c;
    Total_Cost = integer.valueof(apt[0].Total_Cost__c);

Comment: I am getting error here while deploying

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workarounds to avoid Error: "Too many SOQL queries: 101"](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16432/workarounds-to-avoid-error-too-many-soql-queries-101) and all of [these posts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=System.LimitException%3A+Too+many+SOQL+queries%3A+101).

Comment: thanks for the doc can u just point how i can resolve this issue..or if u just modify the above code that would be great

Comment: What does your wrap+normal constructor look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted only has 5 SOQL statements and none of them are in a `for loop`.  The problem could be in any piece of code that executed before this code. The error is saying that you have done 101 SOQL statements and only 100 is allowed.

Have a look at your debug logs and you should see some SOQL that repeats a lot. That will be the code that needs to be refactored. See [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code) for more information on debugging.